# My Prolog program makes a list, but I can't figure out how to make it stop after 2 entries

Tags: prolog

For some practise; I'm trying to create a program that simulates a maze and shows every possible route between entry and exit. The code creates one of the lists, however it doesn't show both and doesn't stop when it's found them (route 1: **entry,a,b,e,f,exit** and route 2: **entry,a,b,c,d,e,f,exit**), and continuously loops into bigger and bigger routes.

```
% length(X, _), route(entry,exit, X).

%Facts, indicating an adjacent link between one room and another.
link(entry, a).
link(a, b).
link(b, c).
link(c, d).
link(d, e).

link(b, e).
link(e, f).
link(f, c).

link(f, exit).

%Searches for the path in an increasing order of length 'route'.
route(X, Y, [X, Y]) :- link(X,Y).
route(X, Y, [X | TY]) :- link(X, T), route(T, Y, TY).
```

Example from console:

| ?- route(entry, exit, A).
A = [entry,a,b,c,d,e,f,exit] ;

A = [entry,a,b,c,d,e,f,c,d,e,f,exit] ;

A = [entry,a,b,c,d,e,f,c,d,e,f,c,d,e,f,exit] ;

A = [entry,a,b,c,d,e,f,c,d,e,f,c,d,e,f,c,d,e,f,exit]

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Some edits that might be of interest. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65545714/how-can-i-get-my-maze-program-to-create-and-print-two-route-lists-to-the-console/65546322#65546322

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to make this *iterative deepening* path search stop from looking for further successes after the first one is to cut at the end of the goal:

```
?- length(X, _), route(entry,exit, X), !.  
X = [entry,a,b,e,f,exit].
```

Once *success* brings Prolog's "finger" past the `!`, any attempt to redo and move the finger back leftwards is disallowed. So Prolog stops after the first success.

For multiple solutions: hopefully there is something like [library(solution_sequences)](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/_SWI_/library/solution_sequences.pl) around.

There we have `limit(+Count,:Goal)`:

```
?- limit(2,route(entry, exit, A)).
A = [entry,a,b,c,d,e,f,exit] ;
A = [entry,a,b,c,d,e,f,c,d,e,f,exit].
```

The [source code for limit](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/_SWI_/library/solution_sequences.pl?show=src#limit/2), which is written in Prolog. It uses state-changing predicates, but can it be written without those?

Answer (score 0):

**1.** First `path predicate` is the base case.

**2.** Second `path predicate` searches all possible routes for the given `Start` and `End Node`.

---

```
link(entry, a).
link(a, b).
link(b, c).
link(c, d).
link(d, e).
link(b, e).
link(e, f).
%link(f, c).
link(f, exit).

path(Node,Node,[Node]):-!.
path(StartN,EndN,[StartN|List]):-
    link(StartN,NextN),
    path(NextN,EndN,List).
```

---

**Example:**

```
?-path(entry,exit,Route).
Route = [entry, a, b, c, d, e, f, exit]
Route = [entry, a, b, e, f, exit]
    
?-path(entry,a,Route).
Route = [entry, a]
    
?-path(entry,b,Route).
Route = [entry, a, b]
    
?-path(entry,c,Route).
Route = [entry, a, b, c]
false

?-path(entry,d,Route).
Route = [entry, a, b, c, d]
false

?-path(entry,e,Route).
Route = [entry, a, b, c, d, e]
Route = [entry, a, b, e]

?-path(entry,f,Route).
Route = [entry, a, b, c, d, e, f]
Route = [entry, a, b, e, f]
```

Note: I had to comment link(f,c) to get the correct route for exit or else it'll give you stack limit exceeded, I'm not sure why.